# Creating vCard file programmatically in android

Tags: android

I am using the following code to read contacts and create a vcard file.

```
            String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
            Uri uri=Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);


            try {
                fd = cr.openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
            try {
                fis = fd.createInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            byte[] buf = new byte[(int)fd.getDeclaredLength()];
            try {
                if (0 < fis.read(buf))
                {
                    vCard = new String(buf);
                    writer.write(vCard);
                    writer.write("\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

But while going through the list of contacts, I get the error:

> ERROR/MemoryFile(284):
>   MemoryFile.finalize() called while
>   ashmem still open.

And my generated .vcf file is missing some contacts and also does not end properly.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Guys. Anybody has any clue on how to get rid of this error???

Comment: How do I bump this request?? Anybody can suggest me some other forum where this can be answered?

Answer (score 1):

You need close stream fis

```
        try {
            fis = fd.createInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] buf = new byte[(int)fd.getDeclaredLength()];
        try {
            if (0 < fis.read(buf))
            {
                vCard = new String(buf);
                writer.write(vCard);
                writer.write("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Close stream
        fis.close();
```

Comment: Also close writer after finish writing all records

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I used a open source [android-vcard](http://code.google.com/p/android-vcard/) jar to write the contacts to vcard.

Comment: Could you point me to some link which has a description of the jar file you used